# Sbt Project dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I am quite new to Scala and sbt. What is the command to be used in the command line to refresh the dependencies as per the updated build.sbt ?

I already tried building my project in Intellij but it doesn't help. On a side note, what is the sbt alternative command for mvn build ?

Answer (score 1):

To say to sbt to reload your changes, use **reload** command. You can read more about sbt commands for [SBT@0.13](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html), for [SBR@1.x](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html)